# Difference between two methods to confirm AWS SNS topic subscription confirmation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I'm attempting to subscribe an SNS topic to a HTTPS endpoint I own. I'm reading the docs on how to process incoming messages from SNS and how the subscription confirmation needs to be done. I see two methods of confirmation:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-http-https-endpoint-as-subscriber.html - Using the subscribeURL. We can perform a HTTP get request on the "SubscribeURL" attribute value and that would confirm the subscription.
- Calling the ConfirmSubscription [API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_ConfirmSubscription.html) - We pass the SNS Topic ARN and the token received when SNS sends a confirm subscription message to the SNS endpoint.

I'm trying to understand what's the difference between the two methods. The most obvious one to me was this - The choice of using the API will require AWS credentials since the request needs to be signed. But seems like the same call will succeed with just the HTTP GET request?

What's the best practice out there (if any) and/or which method is the one being followed by other folks using AWS/SNS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a difference -- these two alternatives are in fact the same thing.

The `SubscribeURL` attribute is a pre-constructed (by the service) link to the `ConfirmSubscription` action on the SNS API endpoint.

The API accepts GET or POST.  No signature is required in this case.

> This call requires an AWS signature only when the `AuthenticateOnUnsubscribe` flag is set to "true".
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_ConfirmSubscription.html

Answer (score 0):

Before SNS will talk to an endpoint, you need to prove that you control that endpoint.  So your options are to write some code that can do it automatically (most of the SDKs support this) or to capture the token, and by returning it via the API call prove that you control it.

This is a one-time procedure, so you do not need to deploy any AWS credentials to your API endpoint - you can do it from a different system.

We generally build the confirmation handler into the application.

Comment: I was able to understand the part of us attempting to prove that we control the endpoint, I'm able to establish the SNS subscription confirmation, but since there were two different methods which existed to do that, I was trying to understand what's the difference (if any) while using the two methods? 

But I appreciate your input on it, thanks again!